# RestKit vs direct CoreData

Tags: core-data, restkit

I understand that RestKit is using AFNetworking for 'networking' aspect, which is cool. The other aspect of RestKit is object mapping and core data. Can anybody tell me the pros and cons of using RestKit object mapping on top of CoreData vs directly using CoreData? Any special advantages of using RestKit route? Any other advantages of using RestKit? Any drawbacks?

Answer (score 0):

RestKit sits on top of CoreData. The main benefit is object mapping (for received data but also for uploading). It also deals with RESTful URL schemes. If you need these features you should use it.

If you just want to store local objects then RestKit won't help you.

Drawbacks: it is a generic framework so it can't be as efficient at runtime as specific code you write. It's a trade off...